# Confusing pointers and arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm trying to understand the mistake in the following code. The code is supposed to switch between two arrays.

What I saw is that it switches only the first 4 bytes. Is the following correct?

1. Passing `&num1` or `num1` is the same (both pass the address of the first element in the array).
2. The `(char**)` casting is wrong. That's because when you pass and array you pass the address it's laid in. So you actually pass here a `void*`.

How can I actually switch between these two arrays only by pointers? Is thatpossible?

I know it is possible if from the beginning I had defined `char **num1` and `char **num2`. But I want it to stay with the array notation!

```
#include <stdio.h>
void fastSwap (char **i, char **d)
{
    char *t = *d;
    *d = *i;
    *i = t;
}
int main ()
{
    char num1[] = "hello";
    char num2[] = "class";
    fastSwap ((char**)&num1,(char**)&num2);
    printf ("%s\n",num1);
    printf ("%s\n",num2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As a side note, try to avoid using one letter variable names, it makes the code harder to read.

Comment: *But I want it to stay with the array notation!* Why? The fact that you're using arrays instead of pointers is the root of your problem.

Comment: Just reading your title, I suggest reading section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Passing &num1 or num1 is the same (both pass the address of the first element in the array). Am I correct?

No. The first one is a pointer to **the array itself** (of type `char (*)[6]`), whereas in the second case, you have a pointer to the first **element** (of type `char *`; an array decays into a pointer to its first element when passed to a function).

> The (char*) casting is wrong

Indeed, you are casting a `char (*)[6]` to a `char **`.

> So you actualy pass here a void (Am i correct?).

No. Non sequitur. I don't see how the `void` type is relevant here. You have pointers, arrays, and eventually pointers to arrays.

---

Arrays are not pointers. Your code is trying to swap arrays, which does not make sense, since assignment to arrays is not permitted. What you probably want is

I. either get pointers to the first character of each string, and then swap the pointers themselves, like this:

```
void swap_pointers(const char **a, const char **b)
{
    const char *tmp = *b;
    *b = *a;
    *a = tmp;
}

const char *p1 = "hello";
const char *p2 = "world";
swap_pointers(&p1, &p2);
```

II. Or use actual arrays, and you swap their *contents:*

```
void swap_contents(char *a, char *b, size_t n)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        char tmp = a[i];
        a[i] = b[i];
        b[i] = tmp;
    }
}

char a1[] = "hello";
char a2[] = "world";
swap_contents(a1, a2, strlen(a1));
```

Also, you may want to read [this](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptr2.html).

Comment: Thank you very much for the comprehensive answer. But is there no way to just take the block of bytes that num1 is laid in, and swap this whole block with the whole block of num2 (without a loop) ? How come ? Cause It sounds a very trivial operation.

Comment: @KakaMaka No. It's a basic algorithmic question. You can't read and write an entire array in `O(1)` time. Just like there's no real `O(n)` sorting algorithm, etc.

Answer (score -1):

```
1. Passing &num1 or num1 is the same (both pass the address of the first element in the array)
```

Not true, `&num1` gives you a pointer to a pointer that points to the entire character string "hello" (char*[6]) while `num1` is just a pointer to the character block "hello" (char[6]).

```
2. The (char*) casting is wrong. That's because When you pass and array you pass the address it's laid in. So you actualy pass here a void (Am i correct?).
```

It is still not a void, it's just a pointer to a character pointer.  If it were void, then it would be perfectly valid to do something like `void** myVoid = &num1`.  This will cause a syntax error unless you explicitly typecast your char** to a void** before you assign it.

The problem is your explicit type casting `&num1` as a `char**` which is not correct, it is a `char*[6]`.  But of course, you can't declare a variable as a `char*[6]` so it can't be used in this way.  To fix it you need to declare your `num1` and `num2` as:

```
char* num1 = "hello";
char* num2 = "class";
```

instead and keep everything else the same.  In fact, with this change there is no need to typecast your `&num1` as a `char**` because it already is that.

Comment: "`&num1` gives you a pointer to a pointer" No. `&num1` is a pointer to an array. "while num1 is just a pointer to the character block" No, `num1` gets converted to a pointer to a character.